# When does equality hold in the Minkowski's inequality $| x - y |^a = | x - z |^a + | y - z |^a?$

Tags: inequality, reference-request

More precisely, for which points $x = (x_1, x_2), y = (y_1, y_2)$ and $z = (z_1, z_2)$ in the plane does hold
$$
| x - y |^a = | x - z |^a + | y - z |^a
$$
where $a \in (0,1)$?

Notice that when $a=1, z$ can be any point in the line segment joining $x$ to $y$. That is, $z = t x + (1-t) y$ with $t \in (0,1)$. My conjecture is that for $a \in (0,1), z$ must be in curve like cusp instead of a line joning $x$ and $y$.

In other words, is possible to find out a expression like $z=tx+(1−t)y$
as in the case $a=1$?

Comment: Can you state what the Minkowski inequality is here? $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a normed linear space with the $p$-norm where $p \in (0,1)$.

Comment: This doesn't look like Minkowski. The required condition is $z=x$ or $z=y$.

Comment: Yes, the Minkowski inequality here is 
 is a normed linear space with the $p$
-norm where $p\in(0,1)$ You can think that $n=2$

Comment: I've made a edition in order to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x-z = v$ and $z-y = w$, then your equality is  $| v + w|^a = | v |^a + | w |^a$.

Now Minkowski's inequality says that $| v + w|^a \le | v |^a + | w |^a$ for $a >1$, with equality if and only if $v$ and $w$ are positively linearly dependent; that is, $v = q w$ for some $q \ge 0$, or $v = 0$, or $w = 0$. For  $a <1$, the reverse inequality  $| v + w|^a \ge | v |^a + | w |^a$ holds with the same equality conditions, albeit only if $v$ and $w$ are non-negative. [All this about Minkowski from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality)].

So, starting from here, your conditions for equality are

1. $v = q w$, i.e. $x-z = q (z-y)$ for $q \ge 0$

or 2.  $v = 0$, i.e. $x=z$

or 3.  $w = 0$, i.e. $y=z$

and additionally, for  $a <1$, you need that both $x-z$ and $z-y$ are non-negative.

Comment: Nice, is possible to find out a expression like $z=tx+(1-t)y$ as in the case $a=1$?